# Problem reading bad time format in text/JSON file

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a text/JSON file using pandas. The file has a time field which is formatted like this: 02:42:59 . pandas reads its as an integer so this for example: 4368

I would ideally like this converted to a float of hours or minutes

code to import the text file:

```
data = json.load(codecs.open(p1, 'r', 'utf-8-sig'))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Update the question to show samples of `data` and `df1`.

Comment: Also, I don't understand how `02:42:59` would convert into `4368`.

Comment: I tried to replicate your issue. I didn't get the integer format of time:

>>> sampleJson=json.loads(sampleString)
>>> sampleJson
{'date1': '02:42:59'}
>>> df1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sampleJson,orient="index")
>>> print(df1)
              0
date1  02:42:59
I agree with @JohnGordon. Please update the question with sample data and dataframe.

Comment: Hi Im sorry, the 4368 Wass just a random example since I couldn't find the exact same one. I guess it would transform 02:42:59 to 24259